# TSQL Filtrar Tabla con fechas iguales

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de combinar filtrar una tabla en la cual la fecha hasta es la misma y en este caso quiero que solo muestre la mas reciente por periodo, Les muestro una imagen de lo que quiero . Uso TSQL. Para obtener la primera consulta utilizo la siguiente consulta.

```
 select SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,a.fecha_hasta,112),1,4) +
            SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,a.fecha_hasta,112),5,2) as PERIODO,
                a.*,b.Estado 
                from db_ocg.khd.Hist_Estado_Lima a 
                left join db_ocg.khd.Estado b on
                a.cod_est = b.cod_est
                where 
                a.RUC in ('1046283****') and
                SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,fecha_hasta,112),1,4) = '2019'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por que en vez de SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,fecha_hasta,112),1,4) = '2019' no usas YEAR(fecha_hasta)='2019'

Comment: usaba ello x el tipo de datos pero veo q tmb funciona gracias por la recomendacion, sin embargo agradeceria una ayuda con la pregunta, gracias

Comment: No entiendo del todo tu pregunta podrias explicarmelo un poco mejor y trato de ayudarte

Comment: Deberías poder resolverlo con un `GROUP BY` Y UN `MAX()` para la fecha